# Сколько раз надо указывать шрифт в css

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Я хочу использовать разные шрифты на сайте. Для параграфов один, для заголовков другой. Я знаю, что шрифт могу указать в начале, но он везде будет одинаков. Я указываю каждому тексту шрифт( Так и надо делать или нет?

Comment: По вашим словам получается, что вы указываете шрифт ровно два раза: один раз для параграфов, другой раз для заголовков. В таком случае непонятно, почему бы и нет

Comment: Покажите код - тогда можно будет сказать, надо так делать или нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите использовать определенный шрифт на протяжении всего сайта, например для тега `<p> 'Jaapokkisubtract'`, а для `<div> 'Roboto'`, то вам в CSS файле нужно просто прописать для `div` или `p` определенный шрифт:

```
div{
    font-family: 'Jaapokkisubtract', sans-serif;
}
```

Tакже, вы можете указать шрифт сразу нескольким тегам:

```
div, p, span{
    font-family: 'Jaapokkisubtract', sans-serif;
}
```

Таким образом, при создании `p` или `div` там уже будет шрифт который вы задали.

Answer (score 1):

В .css можно добавить разные шрифты текста для ,  и т.д.

```
h1{ 
 color: #555555;
 font: 16px Atiba Cyrillic;
}
```